# Facebook show : <UserName> likes 404 Not Found

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have standard fb like button on my blog, and when user clicks on it and likes that page, in his facebook activity log there is only " likes 404 Not found.", but with correct link to the page.
Blog is live and running, and for some pages, likes works normal. That is when user click on like button on some "Random page", it shows in his activity as " likes Random Page", with correct thumb image.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try accessing your site with the [Facebook Linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug). Facebook caches the results of its thumbnailer and snippet handler, but the Linter will get a fresh copy from your site.